# Calling a server side function using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

How to call a server side function written in c# using jquery without using pagemethods ?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but I would suggest searching for C#, jquery and ajax in your preferred search engine if you're after information about performing an asynchronous callback to a server method from the client.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid use of [WebMethod] on a page? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `ajax` to make a server side call asynchronously. Since you want to execute a server side method. I would suggest you to expose it as a webmethod in a websservice and then you can call `.asmx/webthodName` using ajax.

But still if you want to do your way then you can creat an `aspx` page which will take certain parameter say (methodName). You can make a `ajax` call to this `aspx` page and using the `methodName` parameter value you can execute the required method and send only the required response after ending the response using `Response.End()`. Hope this makes sense to you.

jQuery ajax example

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'urlOfThePage',
  data: {},
  success: function( data ) {
     //Do your stuff here 
  }
});
```